# What are the requirements for Russian citizens to leave Russia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airports, russia, russian-citizens, moscow

If they already have the documentation, visa, passport and air tickets, can they be stopped at the Moscow airport by their own Customs agents and be made to show proof of funds before being allowed to board?

Comment: AFAIK all you need for Russia immigration to allow you to exit Russia is your international passport. The airline will check that you meet the requirements to transit third countries and enter the destination country (because they may be fined if you do not). Not making an answer because I'm not 100% sure about it.

Comment: I have had the same issue from a chick I've been talking to online . She said they would not let her leave unless she had at least a thousand (Canadian) in the bank. Wich to me sounded pretty fishy so I called the Russian embassy in canada and asked them and they said that sometimes they do make sure that they leave with sufficient amount of money so they don't get stranded or start stealing or turn to prostitution. They mostly Check people who look like students,fairly young people or shady looking people

Comment: If your Russian online girfriend/fiancé tells you she needs funds to show at the airport when coming to see you, it is almost certainly because she's part of a criminal gang who are engaged in [Russian Dating scams](https://ru.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/victims-of-crime/dating-scams/?_ga=1.209645714.1078748344.1489239119). *(Link updated, Thanks to David Richerby for pointing out the 404)*

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick it's also worth noting that she may not be she. The picture is likely to be fake and the person conducting the correspondence may not even be a woman.

Answer (score 16):

There is no exit visa required to leave Russia, so if you have no outstanding legal actions against you, there is no reason that Russian border patrol or Customs will stop you on exit especially to show sufficient funds for the destination.

Comment: @pnuts An exit visa?  Yes there was...

Comment: Does personal experience of my relatives count?

Comment: Ask @VMAtm he can confirm

Comment: @Karlson WHO DARE TO SUMMON ME!

Comment: @VMAtm 'tis I Karlsson on the roof

Comment: @Karlson I don't believe you, you have only one `s` in the nickname.

Comment: @VMAtm Damn! I've been found out!

Answer (score 12):

First of all, according to the [Constitution of the RF article 27.2](http://www.constitution.ru/10003000/10003000-4.htm) every citizen have the right to leave the RF and return to the RF.

However, Russian Law specifies the ways when this constitutional right may be temporarily limited [114-FZ from Aug15 1996](http://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_11376/) [per article 15 of the same law](http://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_11376/5a4fdcdf4ce525c4221a12682fc98e6e3fc9e17a/). These are:

1. having secret clearance
2. having been drafted
3. being a suspect or being accused of a crime
4. being sentenced for a crime
5. evading obligations imposed by the court
6. having procured documents under false pretenses
7. working for the KGB
8. being declared bankrupt (until the resolution of the bankruptcy case)

This list is inclusive and it is enforced by the passport control checkpoint on exit. (Special restrictions exist on travels of minors to prevent human trafficking.)

Customs has a separate checkpoint, they check for a contraband and such, and may prevent you from flying when something suspicious is found.

Absence of funds is not a valid reason to temporarily limit the right to get out of the RF, and even if it was, it is not checked by the customs.

PS.
RF = Russian Federation, full official name of Russia these days.

Comment: `working for the KGB` This organization seized to exist almost 30 years ago

Answer (score 7):

As @mzu already said, there are a lot of checks on borders in Russia, most of them are being made by **passport controls**, not the **customs**. Customs do the checks fir luggage - are there **too many** cash, are there some items prohibited from moving outside the Russia (such as paintings or rare items), are there drugs, etc.

Neither border control nor customs will check one's financial situation, because it's the point of interest for **other** country to check incoming people, and sums per day are different in different countries. The most popular case to get some funds for border control is that if one's who want to get outside the Russia has an unpaid bill, like taxes, driver fee, etc. If such sum is over `10000 RUR` (about `$200`), one **could** be stopped on border. However, if bill are paid (it can be done tight on border via electronic payments) one could continue theor trip without any problem.

So, basically if you'd have been said that someone need money for going through a border checks, the most probable scenario is that you're a target of scam. Do not send money, try to get back to Russia to **see** the person and resolve the situation with direct involvement.