# Is there a way to verify if a Russian resident has applied for a visa to visit the US after a letter of invitation is sent?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, scams

Is there anyway to verify if a person has had an interview at the American embassy in Moscow? Or if the application has even been processed? 
I have sent a letter of request and was told that the visa to visit the US is in process. Is there any way to verify this?

Comment: Let me guess. You also sent money for the visa and the person has either asked for even more money or is no longer responding? I think the only way to know would be if the applicant can check online and gave you the login/password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the requirements for Russian citizens to leave Russia?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85862/what-are-the-requirements-for-russian-citizens-to-leave-russia)

Comment: Visa application has an id, which can be used for a check

Comment: If you were told the interview took place on the 4th of July (or MLK day or  etc) or a weekend, then you would know.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no.  The only source of information available to you is the visa applicant:

> > I would like to know if my friend has applied for a visa and what the status is. Who should I contact?
>
> Your friend, the visa applicant. Under U.S. law, specifically the Immigration and Nationality Act (INA) 222(f), visa records are confidential. Therefore, the visa applicant should inquire at the U.S. Embassy or Consulate abroad where he/she applied regarding necessary information about visa application status. Because of confidentiality of visa records, you’ll need to ask your friend, the visa applicant your questions about whether a visa application was made, or a visa was issued or denied.

Source: https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/frequently-asked-questions/about-visas-the-basics.html

Comment: I found the online source for verification as one mentioned. You need the Embassy location and application number. And NO, i havent send any money but i can feel it coming and a way to" head it off at the pass" if happens. Thanks agsin ;D

Comment: @Bill386 I'd be interested to know whether the applicant ever gives you the application. You should post an answer with the address for the online verification site.